# Using a protocol func with a custom parameter

Tags: swift, xcode, mkmapview, protocols

I would like to use the `mapView` function from the `MkmapviewDelegate` protocol but instead of having annotation being a `MKAnnotation` variable I want it to be from a custom type that inherits from `MKAnnotation`.

The thing is when I write `"viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation"`, I get an error using the methods from my custom class and when I write `"viewFor annotation: MyCustomClass"` the program doesn't use this method and I don't get what I want.

Note: the final goal is to display custom image for annotations that are created dynamically.

Thank you for your answers

**The function:**
[image: The function]

Comment: Dont post code as images, include the code in the question

Comment: not as image, as code ;)

Comment: Yes sorry thought the image was clickable !

Comment: @VictorAguer it doesn't matter if its clickable, we cannot copy/paste it to check it or try out your code and its much less readable than text

Answer (score 0):

You could guard your custom class in `viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation` like:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotation? {
    // we check if the annotation is of type MYCLASS, otherwise we make an early exit with nil
    guard let myClass = annotation as? MYCLASS else {
        return nil
    }
    if myClass.getState() == ... {}
}
```

and then you can use your custom class methods again

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I'm not sure where to write it ! like this : 'extension MapViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    
    guard let marquerChantier = annotation as? MarqueurChantier else {
        return nil
    }'   and then i replace the annotation in the body of the func  with marquerChantier ?

Comment: @VictorAguer i've made an edit to make it more clear